# Docker: Install pip packages in the image, on the host, or both?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, pip

For what I know, the common practice of Python development with Docker is to have:

```
# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In my `Dockerfile`. This way the packages are installed while building the image. But VSCode doesn't recognize them, therefore reporting warning:

[image]

I always just run `pip install -r requirements.txt` *again* on the host. And it works as expected... except it weakens the benefit of Docker. After all, one of the reasons to use Docker is to not worry about how to build all the dependencies on the host, right? For a package with binary dependency, e.g. `numpy`, now I need to know how to build it on *both* alpine (the Docker image) and Mac (the host). And it occupies double disk space too.

Is there a way to install the dependencies once, while enjoying VSCode (or other editor/IDE)'s autocompletion?

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/install-pip-packages-in-the-image-on-the-host-or-both/116250

Comment: Do you develop on the host or in the container? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: @madflow I write code on the host and mount the `src` as a volume to the container.